# Exportar datos de una base de datos y subir archivo a dropbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, embebido, windows-mobile

Me gustaría saber si es posible y si lo es ¿cómo seria el código o un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo para dispositivos móviles o windows CE?.

Estoy programando en visual studio 2008, SQL Compact 3.5, .net Compact.

Answer (score 1):

Cuentas con librerias de .net que permiten interactuar con el servicio de dropbox

[Dropbox.NET is our .NET SDK for API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet)

Los ejemplos utilizan asp.net mvc si te fijas en el [EditController](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Examples/SimpleBlogDemo/Controllers/EditController.cs)
veras que utiliza el `UploadAsync()` para subir el archivo

```
using (var client = this.currentUser.GetAuthenticatedClient())
        {
            if (client == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Home");
            }

            using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
            {
                var upload = await client.Files.UploadAsync("/" + filename, body: mem);

                var metadata = ArticleMetadata.Parse(upload.Name, upload.Rev);

                return Redirect(string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "/Blogs/{0}/{1}",
                    this.currentUser.BlogName,
                    metadata.DisplayName));
            }
}
```

el tema seria validar si desde el Device creado en Win Ce puede usar la libreria

Sino vas a tener que crear un servicio web api en asp.net mvc y enviar el archivo a este para subirlo a dropbox

Comment: leo los documentos y odo lo que dice ahi en el link que usted me dice pero encuentro varios problemas los ensamblados no me lo reconoce la plantlla que estoy utlizando, que otra forma me aconsejaria